# how do you type a Chinese Character in computer?

Tags: characters

What software do most of you using for typing Chinese characters, and is it developed by someone Chinese? I am using Sougou.

Comment: Is your computer running Windows, OS X, or Linux?

Comment: I using windows most time, and a little UBUNTU.

Comment: http://www.pinyinjoe.com/windows-7/win7-pinyin-setup.htm that should help you

Answer (score 3):

In Windows, there are so many tools to help you to type Chinese characters. Such as [google pinyin](http://www.google.com/intl/zh-CN/ime/pinyin/), [Microsoft pinyin IME](http://www.microsoft.com/china/pinyin/)(if you know pinyin of the Chinese characters), and so on. If you use Ubuntu, there are also many options, type the command to install scim `sudo apt-get install scim scim-pinyin`, or you can try iBus(I use it in linux):

```
sudo apt-get install ibus ibus-clutter ibus-gtk ibus-gtk3 ibus-qt4 
sudo apt-get install ibus-pinyin
```

after you install them, enable or disable them by hitting Control + Space by default then you can type Chinese characters by Pinyin.

Comment: `scim` is obsolete. Recent Ubuntu have `ibus` pre-installed, you might need to install `ibus-pinyin`.

Comment: @hrzhu I haven't use Ubuntu for a few years, things changed:)

Answer (score 3):

I will give you another way to input Chinese without installing any software.

1. Enter [Gmail](https://mail.google.com) setting
2. In General setting, under Language
3. Check "**Enable input tools - Use various text input tools to type in the language of your choice**", and Click **Edit tools** choose 拼音 or 漢語拼音
4. You can type Chinese when you are writing email.

[image]

And I believe it works with [Google Drive](http://drive.google.com/) too.